incrementalCache missing in unstable_cache nextjs 14
i would like to use unstable_cache here but i am getting error above.
My ideia is caching my data that is coming from firesotre.
can someone build a code that unstable_cache works with firestore
const [rules, setRules] = useState<RulesProps[]>([])
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
      collection(db, 'users', userId, 'rules'),
      (snapshot) => {
        const rulesData: RulesProps[] = []
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          rulesData.push(doc.data() as RulesProps)
        })
        setRules(rulesData)
        setLoading(false)
      },
    )
    return () => {
      unsubscribe()
    }
  }, [])

